# What is homebrew? Should I use it in normal games?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, homebrew, terminology

I keep on hearing about homebrew in D&D and I was just wondering what it meant.

Comment: The question specifically asks about "homebrew" in the context of D&D, and the answers cover that. It seems like there should be some mention, however, that "homebrew" can also refer to an entire RPG system itself.

Comment: what is a normal game?  Please clarify in the text of your question what you mean by that.

Comment: The "Should I use it" part is probably a duplicate of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68005/is-homebrewing-dd-okay or https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99366/are-there-guidelines-for-homebrewed-content.  Removing the "Should I use it in normal games?" part so you can get a concise definition of homebrew would be great.

Answer (score 54):

Homebrew is beer or other alcoholic beverages brewed at home as opposed to those brewed commercially and bought at a shop.

By analogy, [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew) is any major addition to or omission from the official rules of a game (including RPG but also video and board games) that a particular gaming group uses. For minor changes, the usual expression is [house-rules](/questions/tagged/house-rules); where a house rule becomes homebrew is an ill-defined line.

For example, there is a common house rule in Monopoly that fines and taxes are put aside and collected by anyone landing on Free Parking - it's not in the official [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf). The Speed Die rules at the start of that Hasbro Monopoly ruleset are [optional-rules](/questions/tagged/optional-rules); an official variant made by the maker of the game. The ruleset for Monopoly that combines elements of poker, darts, and deep-sea fishing is well into homebrew territory.

Whether you should use it depends on whether you think you will enjoy it. Like homebrew beer, some of it is really, really good but most of it is really, really bad.

Comment: I, for one, would like to see the homebrew of Monopoly that involves poker and darts. The deep-sea fishing is a bit much. :)

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever seen “homebrew” applied to home-made content for video games, only ever “mods” or more rarely “hacks” and “TCs”. “Homebrew” does get used for computer hardware, and IIRC was used in the early days of personal computing for wholly amateur video games.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Homebrew in video game context is used fairly commonly in the ROM hacking scene to differentiate an entirely new game on an old system from a hack / mod of an existing one. 
https://www.romhacking.net/homebrew has many examples of differing (and sometimes questionable) quality.

Comment: Ironically, the inclusion of hotels in Monopoly started as a house rule...

Comment: @Draco18s of course, the whole game was homebrew until Parker Bros published it.

Comment: The difference between homebrew and house rules seems fairly clear to me. 'House Rule' modifies a rule of the game, 'Homebrew' (like its origins imply) involves making something new. Parking Space Payouts is a House Rule, ditching the dice for some fishing rods is Homebrew. In a D&D context: gaining inspiration whenever you burp is a house rule, but adding a new weapon would be homebrew.

Comment: @DaleM Well, there's that. But I meant that even Parker Bros' original rules didn't include hotels. There's three or four rules that have been added to the official rules over the years (all of which have made the game worse). There's also the "House Rules Edition" from 2014... (Heck, the printing in 1935 didn't even come with player tokens).

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Ohh, of course! The homebrew for closed consoles is very much in the same spirit. How could I forget those.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The term "Homebrew" definitely exists for the console scene, but that usually has "illegal" connotations because it usually involves hacking the system to bypass copy protection. The same term isn't really popular for PC because they're usually just called "Mods" regardless of how deep you need to modify the game. If you need to do RAM modification that's still "modding", but modding for consoles are usually hardware... the terms are kind of all mixed up.

Comment: I don't think this is even accurate... houserules are alterations to existing rules, while homebrew is created content.

Comment: @Ifusaso how do you use a hoserule nobody created? How would you even know about it until somebody did?

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of sleep, but I'm missing your point. Obviously somebody "created" the houserule... by adjusting the existing rules (for instance, one of my GM's does nat 1's always succeed... in the worst way possible). I'm saying that my understanding of homebrew is raw content that doesn't exist in the game (for instance, an entire new class)

Comment: @T.J.L.: We actually did use poker in Monopoly. When a lot went up for auction, instead of bidding wars, we would get a deck of cards and get people to bid on each card (you could have as many cards as you wanted but the first bidder cycled for each card). When no one wanted to buy more cards, the dealing stopped and whoever presented the best 5-card poker hand received the lot (the monopoly lot, not the money). Since you lost the money you paid for the cards, this deincentivized rich bullies and introduced the ability for poor players to luck into getting a lot anyway.

Comment: @Ifusaso and I’m saying that can be considered a *big* house rule.

Comment: @T.J.L. Well, you have to have access to a boat.

Answer (score 46):

### What is 'Homebrew'?

**Homebrew** material is fan-made content designed to supplement first-party material.

It is distinguished from **house rules** by being game *content* rather than game *rules*.  For example, a new kind of monster you create using the guidelines in the DMG is a homebrew monster. A new rule you make that says dwarves get a +1 to attack rolls against goblins is a house rule.

It is distinguished from **rulings** by being (ideally) a thought-through, perhaps playtested, complete system or subsystem intended to be reused potentially across multiple campaigns, as well as by being content rather than a more abstract rule-like entity.  For example, if you have to handle one of your players throwing a Locathah's spear back at them and decide on the fly that a roll of 15+ will hit and deal 3d6+Str damage that's your ruling on the matter.  When you later design new weapon stats for a Locathah's spear for use whenever your players get ahold of one, you've created a homebrew weapon.

The boundaries between these terms are not always clear, distinct lines, but often fuzzy boundaries.  For example, if you house rule dwarves as getting a +1 to rolls v.s. goblins, and goblins a +1 v.s. elves, and elves a +1 v.s. dwarves you've created a homebrew 'racial enmity' subsystem out of a series of houserules that may have developed independently over time.  If one day one of your players decides they want to shove their souls in a broomstick to animate it and you decide that it works but now they can't get out of said broomstick, you may find you've essentially committed to coming up with a homebrew 'broomstick person' race as a result of your rulings.  Furthermore, it is often desirable when replacing an on-the-fly ruling with homebrew material (whether your own or someone else's) to ensure that the new material continues to have or allow the same results from the same actions as you'd let the players' accomplish so far.  Consequently rulings you make on the fly can often shape and constrain the sort of homebrew you later come up with-- though you could always instead make use of a retcon or other continuity breaking solution if need be.

---

### Should I use homebrew in normal games?

#### In theory:

Yes, ideally, all the time.

Unless you believe that the 5e first party sourcebooks are divinely inspired, inerrant, and completely sufficient on their own for every aspect of play (for the record, they aren't), there ought to exist material that is superior in some way either for games in general or at least for your particular game.  Thus, the ideal, perfect 5e game must always include homebrew material because that material must be what makes up what is lacking in the base system or base system+third-party content that prevents it from being the absolute objectively perfect rpg system for the particular group and campaign and surrounding environmental circumstances the game takes place in.  So, on a purely theoretical level, the theoretical limit of game quality requires that any actual set of rules that we can accept are not perfect or at least not complete could at least theoretically be improved by the addition and/or substitution of the *right* homebrew material.

#### In practice:

Practically speaking, there's nothing inherently *wrong* or *right* with homebrew material, and so sometimes it's good to include and sometimes it's not.  It's probably a good idea to include some homebrew if people are bored of the published material and want new options.  It's probably a bad idea to include some homebrew material if all of the players strongly distrust your ability to come up with material that isn't terrible, whether or not that distrust is justified, or if you don't have the ability to share the homebrew material with the group beforehand and the group doesn't like finding out about that sort of thing later.

Every time you start a campaign or one-shot or other D&D-y-thing you have to decide what material you are going to include in your game. Myriad social and artistic considerations can play into those decisions, and sometimes it's a better idea to not use something *because* it is homebrew or, yet more rarely, to use something *because* it's homebrew.  Far more often, the correct decision is made based on the individual merits of the content in question-- is it well written?  Are my players excited about it?  Does it fit the feel I want?  Am I excited about it? Is it balanced? etc.

Comment: Your point about divine inspiration misses the additional fact that homebrew material is also not divinely inspired.  By the same reasoning there probably cannot exist any "objectively perfect" homebrew material either.  Homebrew material may be better or worse than first party / officially authorized material.  "You should always use homebrew material" does not logically follow from "the existing rules as written are imperfect."

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I think I now understand.

Comment: There is, however, one specific case where one must never use homebrew and must at least pretend that the sourcebooks are divinely inspired:  D&D Adventurers League.

Comment: *Unless you believe that the 5e first party sourcebooks are divinely inspired, inerrant, and completely sufficient on their own for every aspect of play*  The only adjective that you left out was _perspicacious_  8^D And as you say, they aren't.

Comment: _"designed to supplement first-party material"_ Is that really a requirement for something to be considered "homebrew"? The first RPG group I ever took part in developed our own rule system from the ground up, taking loose inspiration from multiple other P&P and CRPG systems. We often referred to it as a "homebrew system", but your definition seems to imply we were incorrect to do so.

Comment: @jmbpiano This question is about D&D 5e.  It would be wrong to call your system 5e homebrew, or homebrew material in the context of 5e.  A 'homebrew system' is totally a thing, though, as you say, and I have heard that used primarily like you indicate: for a system developed non-professionally. Nevertheless, I'm not sure it is good to discuss that here.  It might make more sense to ask another, broader, [tag:terminology] question just about what 'homebrew' means in general. If you want to post that, I'll rework this answer for it and +1 it.

Comment: @GrandOpener Whether either is "divine inspiration" is a red-herring; any content that is not an Adventure Book is going to in some way be Homebrew. If I were to have my players run a campaign in Neverwinter fighting Human Necromancer Darwin Kale, who is not documented in a pregenerated Adventure, that's a form of Homebrew. But the point is, unless you are running a pregenerated Adventure (and I would argue even if you are), some form of Homebrew is mandatory to a game to be original and engaging.

Comment: @GrandOpener Ah, but I say you should always use the *right* homebrew, which, of course, would in fact be divinely inspired, should that be important to it being good.  I do *not* say you should use whatever homebrew you can find.  Just that, should the work be imperfect, there is *something* additional, albeit perhaps an unreachably difficult set of things, that would improve it.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil   
> "Thus, the ideal, perfect 5e game must always include homebrew material"  

I think you mean *your* ideal game. 5e (and any ruleset) is never perfect, but it may be ideal if a) you're its maker and its your realized vision or b) you simply find the risk of homebrew less than ideal.   

Your suggestion is very subjective and not an answer.

Comment: @Eldebryn Nope!  While all extant rulesets may not be perfect, that does not prevent a perfect ruleset from existing.  Whether or not you are the maker of a system has almost nothing to do with it; if you think it's perfect then my answer doesn't apply to you, if you can correctly acknowledge that 5e isn't perfect and could benefit from additional material-- as WoTC does implicitly every time they publish new material and the lead designers do explicitly on Twitter and stream all the time-- then you are agreeing with that section of this answer.

Comment: @Eldebryn b) is completely irrelevant.  Adding any given homebrew could be a bad idea 99.9999999997% of the time and created homebrew could be bad with similar odds and either bad for the average game quality, but that would have absolutely nothing to do with what is *optimal*.  Adding a cat to your track team is usually a bad idea but if there's a .00000000000000001% chance that cat is a cheetah and not disqualifiable the optimal theoretical configuration is still going to be a 100% cheetah track team.  Giving up may be the right choice in practice, but it is objectively suboptimal in theory.

Comment: Great description, but I disagree with "Yes, ideally, all the time." to the point that I wonder if this question isn't in violation of being too broad/opinion based.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil I get your point, but saying that someone should always use the _right_ homebrew implies a (magical?) ability to accurately determine rightness of homebrew.  Absent that ability, any specific version of homebrew is not any more likely to be perfect than the base rules.  We're in agreement that a theoretical set of perfect rules can be imagined (though it probably doesn't actually exist), and that it is almost certainly not word-for-word the core rules.  The problem is the "yes, ideally, all the time" conclusion does not logically follow from that observation.

Answer (score 13):

### What is Homebrew?

In the context of role-playing games, "homebrew" is anything made up by players/DMs/RPG fans that are not from the official source books.

For D&D this is typically going to be new races, magic items, subclasses, monsters and so on.

As other answers have pointed out, there are also "house-rules" which are a little bit different, though the lines can get blurred. (House-rules are more like variations of official rules that you like to use. For example, ruling that drinking a healing potion is only a bonus action rather than a normal action would be a house-rule).

### Should I use it in normal games?

If you want to!

I doubt any DM or player has played for long without at least *wanting* to create something of their own. A good RPG encourages creativity, and the temptation of including some cool monster or magic item of your own in an adventure (or something cool that somebody else created and posted on a fan site) is probably going to hit anyone at some point.

And there is certainly nothing wrong with that

My only advice, DM to DM, would be to try and consider any homebrew idea in the context of the rules and ensure it's balanced. The temptation, sometimes, is to go a bit overboard with something you think is a cool idea only to discover later that it's SO cool - or overpowered - that *every* player has to play your Oojimifrat race and wield a SooperDooper Sword of Ultimate Killing in order to not get overshadowed by every other player with the same thing. (But even then, don't be afraid of mistakes - they can always be rectified, even if it requires admission of mistakes and some frank discussion with your players).

But otherwise...have fun and be wild!

Answer (score 13):

### Should I use Homebrew in my game?

Several others have covered what homebrew is (in-depth alterations to how the game is played that go beyond house rules) so I'm not going to address that half of your question. However, the second Q: **No, not at first.**

Play the game a little bit vanilla and learn the game. Homebrew can be great, but it takes a decent understanding of how the game works to be able to decide what mix is right for your group. In the same way that you probably shouldn't start brewing beer if you've never drunk beer, altering the game without knowing exactly what you're changing it from is a recipe for disaster on a number of fronts.

TL;DR: Homebrew is great, but play some Vanilla D&D before you try it so you'll know WHY you're making the changes.

Comment: Thank you for this warning, I will get some play through knowledge first before attempting any homebrew.

Answer (score 6):

### Definitions

#### House Rules

A **house rule** is a change to the official D&D rules that a group of players use in their own personal games. Usually the players agree to a house rule before starting the game, after which it's the GM's job to enforce it. In D&D Adventurers' League, the GM and players are expected to follow the official rules, but house rules are perfectly fine in private games as long as everyone is on-board.

However, keep in mind that:

1. House rules need to be explained to new players, some of whom might prefer the standard rules.
2. House rules are easier to forget, because players can't look them up.

#### Rulings

Ideally, players and especially GMs will know the rules. However, D&D has a lot of rules, and they are sometimes ambiguous or interact in weird ways. When this happens, many books advise the GM to make a **ruling** on the spot to keep the game going rather than stopping to look it up.

Unlike house rules, players don't agree on rulings ahead of time - they can't, because they didn't think of it until it happened. The GM simply has to use their best judgment and decide what's most reasonable.

Later, you can look up the official rules and decide what to do in the future. The greatest danger here is usually that the DM's ruling creates a precedent that's ripe for abuse. In this case, the DM might decide to use the official rules in the future. If the GM isn't concerned about that and the group prefers the GM's decision over the official rules, they can adopt it as a new house rule.

#### Homebrew

When a GM creates a new monster, spell, magic item, or even an entire class for use in their own games, they are **homebrewing**. Usually they start with an existing monster/spell/whatever and modify it, but not always.

Homebrewing may or may not include creating new rules. Creating a whole new class should probably be called a "rules change". Creating a new monster by adding *Regeneration* to a chimera doesn't require any new rules. A monster with a new ability created specifically for it is sort of a gray area.

Again, none of this would be legal in D&D Adventurers' League, but it's perfectly fine in private games.

Also, if the GM writes the campaign themselves (as opposed to using a published campaign), I might call it a **homebrew campaign**. Even if the GM uses only monsters, spells, and magic items from the core rulebooks, the GM is still mixing it all together on their own.

It's also possible to homebrew a whole new game with its own rules. This is a monumental task, and not something that I would recommend.

### Why Homebrew?

#### To Shake Things Up and Avoid Metagaming

Separating player knowledge from character knowledge can be difficult, even for experienced players. Many players will recognize a troll even if their PCs have never seen one before. The players now have an annoying choice to make:

1. Bust out the fire and acid, even though their PCs might not know to use those things.
2. Ignore their metagame knowledge and do the "wrong thing" even though (as players) they know better.

The GM can avoid this by inventing a new monster similar to a troll with a different look, such as "a Large gorilla-like creature with blue fur and a pair of sinister horns". Against this new monster, the players will likely use their standard tactics, notice that it regenerates, and experiment to figure out how to stop the regeneration.

In this case, the GM doesn't even to change the stat block - just use the troll's normal stats and say it attacks with its horns rather that its bite. This isn't really homebrewing so much as **reskinning** the monster, but it's an easy way to give experienced players a new challenge to overcome.

Another simple homebrew is to create a variation of an existing monster. Published adventures do this all the time - the author likes the look and feel of an existing monster, but the regular version isn't quite right, so they make a variant. You can add a ghast's *Stench* to the regular flesh golem to make a decaying flesh golem, or add a manticore's *Tail Spikes* to an otyugh to make a mutated otyugh with a ranged attack. From there, you can start making more elaborate changes and creating entirely new creatures as you get comfortable.

#### To Create Something Unique

A lot of GMs create new things not out of need, but simply because they want something in their game to feel like their original work. Just to be clear, I think that even if a GM runs a published adventure exactly as written, they're doing original work - each GM will use different words, make different rulings, and portray NPCs somewhat differently. But sometimes a GM has a particular vision in mind that they can't quite realize with the core rulebooks, and they build it through homebrewing instead.

GMs also do this to work in elements from a PC's backstory. My current campaign (which is actually a Pathfinder game, but the idea is the same in 5e) is based on a published adventure, but I have a few PCs with backstories that I've incorporated into the main story. To do this, I've homebrewed several new NPCs, a few new monsters, and a couple other things.

#### To Give the Players More Options

Sometimes players feel restricted by the class, spell, and magic item options presented in the rulebooks. Maybe they want to play a ranger with a limited version of a rogue's Sneak Attack - the GM can create rules for this (5e tries to minimize the need for this with class archetypes, but it still happens sometimes). Maybe they want a spell like Fireball that freezes rather than burns - the GM can make one (it's rumored that this is why *cone of cold* exists - Gary Gygax decided that *fireball* should be able to destroy treasure, so his players requested another spell that wouldn't).

These are probably the most difficult and dangerous homebrews, because GMs have to live with them. If a homebrewed monster turns out tougher than expected, the GM can change it behind the scenes - the players won't know it's Str is now 16 instead of 18. But when homebrews are given to players, changing them often means a player now has to settle for a lesser version of that cool spell or ability they loved to use. Homebrewed classes in particular are notoriously difficult to balance, since classes have so many parts.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew simply means **any** content created by the group, rather than the publisher of the game.  Most common homebrew content are adventures, dungeons, character backgrounds, npc's, item & monster variants, locations, lore.

Most tabletop rpg's support homebrew content (see 5e Dungeon Masters Guide) and many games will encourage the GM to make the game 'their own'.

Some GM's try to keep homebrew at the bare minimum to save time, or out of concern to accidentally break the game.  Others create entire campaign settings and spend hundreds of hours into fleshing out the history & lore.  And finally, some GM's are game designers who even create their own core mechanics from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is the set of rules that are not found in any written rulebook or supplement, but which arise from the GM and, somewhat less often, from the players.  These are typically unique to either a GM or to a campaign, although sometimes one GM will take a good idea from another.

1. Sometimes these rules arise because something odd happened in a game that just wasn't covered in the written rules.  Then the GM made a ruling to handle it, and if that situation arises often enough the ruling is also used often.
2. Sometimes these rules arise because the GM thinks an established, written rule is defective in some way (this includes everything from "That's not fun!" to "That doesn't fit my game world!") and changes it.
3. Sometimes these rules arise because the GM wants to introduce something new into his campaign.  Most often, this will be a new monster, a new character class/race, or a new magic item.

Usually when I hear "homebrew" I think naturally of the third category-- something substantial and distinctive-- but I would argue that the first two categories (sometimes called "house rules") also fit the bill.

Comment: This seems to be blending house rules with homebrew, when I think they’re much more distinct.

Comment: If you "would argue that the first two categories... ...also fit the bill", then do so.